# Thinkpad X1 Yoga: accelerometer Acer BMA150 not working

Tags: hardware, thinkpad, input-devices

The Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga ships with an Acer BMA150 accelerometer. This device is recognized by the Kernel (running Ubuntu 16.04 with Mainline kernel 4.6-RC2):

```
root# uname -a
Linux x1 4.6.0-040600rc2-generic #201604031130 SMP Sun Apr 3 15:32:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root# dmesg| grep BMA                      
[    9.611130] input: Acer BMA150 accelerometer as /devices/virtual/input/input15

# udevadm info -q all -n /dev/input/js0
P: /devices/virtual/input/input15/js0
N: input/js0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/js0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input15/js0
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_ACCELEROMETER=1
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=9614435
```

From above I understand that this device is detected as a joystick and should be usable via `/dev/input/js0`. Using `jstest` from package `joystick` however gives an error message:

```
root# /usr/bin/jstest /dev/input/js0       
jstest: Operation not permitted
```

The command above was executed as `root`. File permissions look good:

```
root# ls -l /dev/input/js0 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root input 13, 0 Apr 12 12:15 /dev/input/js0
```

There's no further error showing up in `dmesg` or in any file in `/var/log`.
Using jstest on my Wacom Inutos Tablet succeeds (it also acts as joystick device).

Can anyone help me to get the accelerometer working?

Answer (score 2):

This device is used for harddisk shock prevention, and its detection as a joystick is an error. You get this error message because testing a non-joystick with the joystick tester doesn't work for obvious reasons.

To get it to work, at least on other thinkpads, you can install `hdapsd`. It needs to be run as a daemon - it reads the accelerometer data and parks the hard drive heads when critical motion of the laptop is detected.

For newer devices, specifically yours, `hdapsd` doesn't support the hardware. You can install `iio-sensor-proxy` to test your laptop with it. Other Yoga laptops work with it, according to their [Github](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy) page.

Comment: As far as I know hdaps works on top of detected accelerometers and therefore scans "joysticks" as well: hdapsd -v shows "Thu Apr 21 11:25:47 2016: Trying input for Acer BMA150 accelerometer
Thu Apr 21 11:25:47 2016: Got hdaps_input_nr=-1
Thu Apr 21 11:25:47 2016: Could not find a suitable interface" - so I guess the above "jstest: Operation not permitted" is still the underlying problem here.

Comment: People get exactly the same `jstest: Operation not permitted` and the devices still work flawlessly with hdaps, but on older devices. Reference: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7238136.html from 2013

Comment: The hint regarding iio-sensor-proxy is super helpful. Thanks.